# Reference of ref arguments

Tags: c#, reference

I'd like to use the heap address (reference) value of a ref argument in a function. The value needs to be that of the reference and not the pointer value at one spot in time, to overcome GC compaction address movements.

The source of this contraption was to be able to cache values of expressions, in a function that gets the expression alongside a ref value, which will be unique enough for my needs.

Concretely - the following code is a generic setter for implementing INotifyPropertyChanged properties.

```cs
protected void SetIfUpdated<T>(ref T backingField, T newValue, Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    if (/*old and new value comparison*/)
    {
        return;
    }
    backingField = newValue;
    NotifyPropertyChanged(this, ReflectionAssist.GetName(expression));
}
```

The downside is that it costs too much for frequently updating properties (the expression manipulation), so users of this code will need to (statically) cache the name of the property themselves. A more usable solution would have been to cache the value of the expression, with the key being the address of the ref argument.

```cs
protected void SetIfUpdated<T>(ref T backingField, T newValue, Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    if (/*old and new value comparison*/)
    {
        return;
    }
    backingField = newValue;
    NotifyPropertyChanged(this, _Dictionary[AddressOf(ref backingField)]);
}
```

So, is there a nice-enough way to do this, without delving into unmanaged APIs of the GC and without using the Debugger/Profiler API?

Comment: Are you sure this will cost too much - have you tested and profiled this?  Seems like premature optimisation to me...  (Also, have you looked into the new `CallerMemberName` attribute?)

Comment: Not premature. :) Tested and profiled. Also - CallerMemberName will solve this, yes, but we're one version behind. (And why would you take away all of my self loathing comments? People need to know that I hate myself for asking this!)

Comment: Could you allow yourself another level of indirection and restrict T to a wrapper class, like a `BackingFieldWrapper<T>`? Then the wrapper class could hold either the expression or a guid.